# where can i found search input textbox on controller action or view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I working on asp.net mvc application by csharp . i face issue I can't find controls search input type textbox .

I search on action controller PendingRequests i can't found it .

also i search on index.html it not exist

so How to get search text box please ?

action controller

```
       public ActionResult Index(string filenumber)
    {
        int employeeFileNo;
        string userRole;

      
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filenumber))
        {
          
            if (int.TryParse(filenumber, out employeeFileNo))
            {
                JDEUtility jde = new JDEUtility();
                userRole = Workforce.GetUserRole(employeeFileNo);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userRole))
                {
                    var EmpName = jde.GetEmployeeName(employeeFileNo);

                    Session[SessionKeys.UserCode] = employeeFileNo;
                    Session[SessionKeys.Username] = EmpName;
                    Session[SessionKeys.RoleCode] = userRole;
                    if (userRole != RoleKey.REQ)
                        return RedirectToAction("PendingRequests", "WorkforceRequests", null);
                    else
                        return RedirectToAction("MyRequests", "WorkforceRequests", null);
                }
                else
                    ViewBag.errorMsg = "unauthorized user";

            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.errorMsg = "incorrect file no";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.errorMsg = "unauthorized user";
        }

        return View();
    }
```

pending request view

```
@model IEnumerable<HR.WorkforceRequisition.Models.WorkforceRequest>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Pending Requests";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Pending Requests</h2>
<hr />
@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewBag.msg))
{
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        @ViewBag.msg
    </div>
}
@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewBag.errorMsg))
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        @ViewBag.errorMsg
    </div>
}
<table id="dtbl" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.WorkforceRequestID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DepartmentCode)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Section)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RequiredPosition)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.JobTitle)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReportingTo)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NationalityCategory)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StatusRemark)
            </th>
            <th>
                Requestor
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.WorkforceRequestID })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WorkforceRequestID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DepartmentCode)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Section)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequiredPosition)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JobTitle)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReportingTo)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NationalityCategory)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StatusRemark)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedByName)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>

</table>



<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#dtbl').DataTable({
                "scrollX": true,
                "pageLength": 10,
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    'copy', 'csv', 'excel'
                ]
            });
        });
</script>
```

expected result is found search text box input on which place

[display text box on pending requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVvuZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, it seems you need search text box in the data table. The search box appears by default as such unless you have set any property to not show it. With your js I am able to see the search box You can try adding   "searching": true property to your data table also. You can check the documentation [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/searching).
Here is a working snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#tableID').DataTable({
          // Enable the searching
                // of the DataTable
                searching: true // will work without this also
            });
        });
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js">
    </script>
  
    <!-- DataTables CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=
"https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  
    <!-- DataTables JS -->
    <script src=
"https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
    </script>
 <table id="tableID" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
          
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Samer</td>
                <td>35</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Rajiv</td>
                <td>30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Suhail</td>
                <td>45</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Manisha</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>Robbert</td>
                <td>68</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>Mike</td>
                <td>25</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>Ere</td>
                <td>23</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>James</td>
                <td>35</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>Walt</td>
                <td>65</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>Jessieca</td>
                <td>28</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>11</td>
                <td>Raghu</td>
                <td>20</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: thank you for support but where i can found search input text box are you mean it exist on #dtbl